# VBA - Autosave in a for, net loop

Tags: excel, vba, autosave

I am building a VBA module to carry out a procedure upon set of conditions, looping and saving the test for each condition continuously until the set is complete. Here is the end of our code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "P:\Data\Excel\Accounting\Josh\VBA project\Saved Refunds\" & planID & "_" & employerName & "_Plan Year 2019 ADP_ACP Refunds.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\Data\Excel\Accounting\Frances\2. Testing project\2019 ADP ACP Test Program\Chris 2019 ADP ACP\ADP Test Template.xlsm"
    
Next RowNum
```

What is happening is as the first test if finished and autosaved, the program is not opening & returning to the ADP Test Template and looping as we have tried to code pre Next RowNum. This does not occur when I code with a manual save as:  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

Any ideas of how to get the program back to the ADP Test Template where the core looping code is and the loop continues? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you opening a workbook in a loop? More code would be helpful.

Comment: use [SaveAsCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas) method. You may need to close the `SaveAsCopy` workbook before the `Next`